# Use PDFKit in Swift package

Tags: swift, xcode

I created a Swift package with some utilities; in one class I use PDFKit; when using this Swift package on a macOS app the linking fails:

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PDFDocument
```

When added PDFKit.framework in the main app the linking succeeds.

Question: How can I use / include PDFKit.framework (and any other framework that is needed) in a Swift package?

As I read frameworks are not compatible with M1 based macs; xcframeworks are; does exists a PDFKit xcframeworks?